# How to disable the main background list item by selecting on popup window

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Actually I have a list by clicking item in list it will get popup window by selecting item in popup window i have disable or remove item in main background list . Am new to android please help me.

Main Activity:

```
 public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,

  int position, long id) {
 newListitems2.clear();
 newListitems2.addAll(itemsList1); 

 dialog = new Dialog(PendingOrdersActitvity.this);
 dialog.setContentView(R.layout.itembumping);
 dialog.show();

 listView1.setTag(position);
 list1=(ListView )dialog.findViewById(R.id.list1);

 ItemBumpingAdapter adapter2 = new ItemBumpingAdapter(PendingOrdersActitvity.this,newListitems2);
 list1.setAdapter(adapter2);

 Button okButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.ok1);
 okButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         dialog.dismiss(); 
     }
 });
 Button cancelButton = (Button)dialog.findViewById(R.id.Cancel1);
 cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         dialog.dismiss();
    }
```

background list Adapter :

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
 {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                     ViewHolder holder;
                     String item = null, qty = null;
                     if (convertView == null) {
                         holder = new ViewHolder();
                         convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
                         holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
                         holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
                         holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
                                 .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
                         holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
                                 .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
                          holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
                         convertView.setTag(holder);

                     } else {

                         holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
                     }
                     parentobjid=newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
                     if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
                     {
                         holder.name.setText("   " +newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
                         holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                         holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                                 .getQuantityDisplay()));
                         holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
                     }
                     else
                     { 
                     holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());       holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
                             .getQuantityDisplay()));
                     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));                       holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
```

Dialog list Adapter:

```
  if (convertView == null) {

     holder = new ViewHolder();
     convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.itembumpingadapter, null);
     holder.qty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.qty);
     holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.item);
     holder.childText = (TextView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.childitem);
     holder.qtyChild = (TextView) convertView
             .findViewById(R.id.qtychild);
     holder.checkbox = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.chckbox1);
     convertView.setTag(holder);

 } else {
     holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
 }
 parentobjid=newListitems.get(position).getParentobjectid();
 if(!parentobjid.isEmpty())
 {
     holder.name.setText("   " +newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
     holder.qty.setText("      "+String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
             .getQuantityDisplay()));
     holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#CC0000"));
 }
 else
 {
    holder.name.setText(newListitems.get(position).getItemnNameDisplay());
     holder.qty.setText(String.valueOf(newListitems.get(position)
             .getQuantityDisplay()));
     holder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
     holder.qty.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
     holder.checkbox.setChecked(false);

     holder.checkbox.setTag(position);
                             holder.checkbox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             int pos=(Integer) v.getTag();//Cast object to integer
             newListitems.get(pos).setChecked(!newListitems.get(pos).isChecked());
         }
     });
     if(newListitems.get(position).isChecked()){
         holder.name.setEnabled(true);
         holder.name.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#DCDBDB"));

         }else{
             holder.name.setEnabled(false);
         }
 }
 return convertView;
```

Comment: Share your code which will help to finds the issue..

Comment: k i will edit the code

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: I edited code please check it @ Amsheer

Answer (score 0):

when click in item in list, create alert dialogue,
in alert dialogue, when click yes to delete that list item, create custom adapter for list and create delete function to delete list item, then call that function in alert dialogue option.

step 1 : write function to delete item in adapter

step 2 : create object for the adapter and call that delete function in dialog positive repsonse.

Comment: will u please explain programatically its urgent necessarey to complete project